# How to insert {{$index}} into an ng-class directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that loops through a list and adds class upon `div` elements like this :

`<div ng-class="{'has-error' : error.degreeYear_{{$index}}} />`

When I inspect the element, the source code shows the index being properly replaced

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error' : error.degreeYear_5} />
```

But, it gives an error, upon clicking which, the angularJS site shows this :

```
Error: $parse:syntax
Syntax Error
Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 18 of the expression [error.degreeYear_{{] starting at [{4}].].
```

I am assuming the angular braces around `$index` is the culprit because the entire `ng-class` expression has to be already enclosed in angular brackets. How should I handle this ?

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error' : error.degreeYear_ + $index} />
```

Since `ng-class` is already an expression there is no need for the double brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error' : error.degreeYear_$index} />
```

ng-class is already a part of angular so need to cover it in double brackets.